# Printing a decimal place

Tags: c, printf, double

How do I get `1.371429` as `01.37`. Is it not `%2.02f`? I need to have a leading zero and also round it to two decimal places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double a = 1.2345666;
    printf("%05.2lf\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, ***05*** says "print 5 columns with leading zeros". ***.2*** says "print decimal digits untill 2 columns". 2 decimal digits + 1 ***.*** + 2 integer part => total 5 columns you have to print.

Comment: Why `lf`?, `f` is enough.

Comment: The `l` in `%lf` is not necessary with `printf` but it is with `scanf`. With `printf` a `float` argument is promoted to `double`.

Comment: I get 00.00 when I use that function.

Comment: never mind. I removed the lf and it worked. With the lf I get 00.00

Comment: @MukitChowdhury, `lf` means `long double`, `l` is ignored in C99 but leads to undefined behavior in C89

Comment: long double and double are same, right? like long int and int. @AlterMann

Comment: @MukitChowdhury, no, they are not the same, who told you that?

Comment: @AlterMann `l` in `lf` has no effect, so it's same as `f`, which is for `double`. `Lf` is for `long double`.

Comment: @user694733, yes, thats what I'm saying :) it  has no effect in C99 and leads to undefined behaviour in C89/C90

Comment: @AlterMann Yes the second part is OK, but I only meant that you should have used uppercase `L` on the first part (*"lf means long double"*).